# Django, TastyPie commit_on_success error

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to add `TastyPie` to my `Django` project to build a RESTful API. I'm using Django `1.8.2`. I'm following the [official tutorial](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html).
I created a resource:

```
# myapp/api.py
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from myapp.models import Entry


class RecipeResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()

# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.api import RecipeResource

recipe_resource = RecipeResource()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include(recipe_resource.urls)),
]
```

I don't think the problem is in my code since it's pretty much a copy & paste from the tutorial. Error occurs when the import is executed:

```
from myapp.api import RecipeResource
```

I am new to Django and TastyPie. Might it be that the TastyPie does not work with Django 1.8.2?

The error:

```
  File "/Users/rafalsroka/Documents/Pthn/Recipes/recipes-backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 1740, in <module>
    class BaseModelResource(Resource):
  File "/Users/rafalsroka/Documents/Pthn/Recipes/recipes-backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 2210, in BaseModelResource
    @transaction.commit_on_success()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'commit_on_success'
```

Comment: No, it seems tastypie hasn't released a 1.8 compatible version, though there has been at least some work on Github. It's not very active, though. It seems people are generally moving away from tastypie, towards django-rest-framework. If it's a new project, drf is definitely worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, I switched to DRF. It's really cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that it is `TastyPie` **lacking** the support for `Django 1.8.2`.
The `commit_on_success` has been removed in this version of `Django`.

I wanted to use the latest release so I switched to [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org).